# Porting Android ICS to Huawei Ascend G300-U8818

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Huawei Ascend G300-U8818 comes with android 2.3.6 os version.

I had successfully compiled the source code of android ICS

**Is it possible to port android ICS on Huawei G300-U8818?**

**If its possible to port then how device performance will be affected?**

Official website of Huawei keeps silence about porting android ICS to Huawei G300-U8818.

How do I make sure that porting is possible or not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

g300 will update to android 4.0 on the 3rd season said by offical website

Answer (score 0):

http://www.modaco.com/forum/650-huawei-ascend-g300-g300modacocom/

ics already out in china works fine in uk

U8815 and u8818 are the same device